# what does "auto asd = (2,3,4,5);" do?

Tags: c++

fast question
what does this do in c++;

```
auto asd = (1,2,3,4,5);
```

note: this does note emit an error

Is this a class?
If it is a struct of data or class or array, can you tell me how to get the individual element value;

When i cout << asd ;
It return always the last number, in this case 5

thanks in advance

Comment: Ignore the parenthesis, they don't do anything here. You are invoking the comma operator on `int`s, ergo you return the final value from the expression.

Comment: what a nice application of my most favourite tool for obfuscation :)

Comment: It invokes the comma operator, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work

Comment: The parentheses are not irrelevant here. Assignment has a higher priority than the comma operator, so without them, the sample would fail to compile

Comment: @divinas This is not assignment, it's initialization. The parentheses are needed because without them this wouldn't compile (a variable name would be expected after each comma).

Comment: @Mansoor: That's absolutely not the case.

Comment: @interjay: You're right, that really isn't assignment. But the sample still fails to compile without parentheses: https://godbolt.org/z/VBDZnH

Comment: @Mansoor The parentheses are necessary. Otherwise, the `,` is not recognized as operator [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5e3cdd6520a763d), but as separator for declarations.

Comment: Missing the point of the question, OP may have thought that the parenthesis would turn the expression into a collection, this is not the case. So yes, they are necessary but do not do what was intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` is an expression of type `int` with a value of 5. The *expression separator operator* `,` evaluates both arguments (sequenced from left to right), but the value of the second argument is the value of the overall expression.

So your code is equivalent to

```
auto asd = 5;
```

Comment: You may be even more precise and say that it is equivalent to `int asd = 5;`.

Comment: @nielsen: But there's nothing in imprecise about `auto`. 5 is a literal of type `int`, always, even in a hypothetical system with 16 bit `char` and `int`.

Comment: You are imprecise.

Comment: And so is your naming of variables, disgraceful.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes it is always an `int` that is why it is more precise to say that it is an `int` rather than saying it is `auto` (= "whatever type the right hand side evaluates to").